# GitGutter's Mapping goes to Command as Plain Text after changing cpoptions

Tags: key-bindings

After some settings (like installing other plugins and defining some mappings), I've found that GitGutter's Next Hunk (`]c` and `[c`) doesn't work any more.

If I do `]cabc` I will see `:<C-U>execute v:count1 . 'GitGutterNextHunk'<CR>abc`in the command, which means the mapping resulted in entering the text in command directly.

When I do `:map` I see `]c` correctly mapped to `<Plug>GitGutterNextHunk`, which is then mapped as:

```
n  <Plug>GitGutterNextHunk * &diff ? ']c' : ":<C-U>execute v:count1 . 'GitGutterNextHunk'<CR>"
```

Btw, calling directly like `:execute 'GitGutterNextHunk'` works.

This all happens after I added the line `set cpoptions="aABceFsd"` to my `.vimrc`. I added the `d` for `tags` integration.  How may that interfere with my mappings?

Comment: With the new information about `cpoptions`. seems like you might get a swifter response by asking the plugin creator directly.

Comment: Maybe.. That's interesting though, as I need to do `nnoremap / /\\v` to achieve what I can do with `nnoremap / /\v` without the `cpoptions` settings in my `.vimrc`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what it looks like [GitGutter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter) by default maps `<Plug>GitGutterNextHunk` and `<Plug>GitGutterPrevHunk` to `]c` and `[c` respectively. However it will not create the mappings in the following scenarios:

- Already have mapping to `<Plug>GitGutterNextHunk`
- Already have a mapping to `]c`
- Have `g:gitgutter_map_keys` set to zero

My best guess is that may have already mapped `]c` in your `vimrc` file.

If you wish to debug further then I would recommend using `:verbose` to see what `]c` is mapped to and where the mapping came from, e.g. `verbose nmap ]c`. Or filtering you mappings via `:filter /GitGutter/ nmap`

Comment: Thanks Peter! I have copied this line from GitGutter: `:nnoremap <silent> <expr> <Plug>GitGutterNextHunk &diff ? ']c' : ":\<C-U>execute v:count1 . 'GitGutterNextHunk'\<CR>"` and I've found that the mapping doesn't work! (`<C-U>` and `<CR>` are shown as plain text). I have to remove the `\`s to get it working. Is it my setup problem or the plugin's?

Comment: That line (re-)creates a `<Plug>’ mapping. `<Plug>` mapping should only be defined by plugins. Remove that line from your `vimrc`. You want to find out why GitGutter isn’t creating the hunk mappings by default or you want to remap, e.g `nmap ]g <Plug>GitGutterNextHunk`.

Comment: Mm.. To clarify, 1. I don't have any related mapping in `.vimrc` or `init.vim`.. 2. `nmap ]g <Plug>GitGutterNextHunk` has the same result as I used `]c`: Plain text `<C-U>` and `<CR>` 3. Removing the backslashes from the GitGutter line works. I guess the backslashes is causing `\<C-U>` to be interpreted as plain text. Should I fix the plugin?

Comment: Please provide a link to your `vimrc` file or append a snippet of it to your post

Comment: Thanks Peter, that motivated me to try to reproduce with minimal `.vimrc` (which I should have thought of before asking, silly me). The issue disappeared after removing `set cpoptions="aABceFsd"` from my `.vimrc`. I have modified the question and please see if that line is really the cause of the issue. (If so, please kindly explain)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% sure *how* this is happening, but it's happening *because* you are setting your `'cpoptions'` incorrectly: when using `:set` to set a string option, you should *not* enclose the desired value in quotes:

```
set cpoptions=aABceFsd
```

As an aside, the documentation for `'cpoptions'`recommends that if you just want to add the `d` flag to the default value, you should use the "+=" feature of set:

```
set cpoptions+=d
```